# More compact Eclipse autocomplete code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Eclipse is great in suggesting standard pieces of code when needed and helping in autocompleting the hints into your code.

For example, in ADT, if I write this piece of code:

```
Runnable r = new
```

if I press CTRL-Space this is what I get, automatically:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

It's fantastic!
But generally, after this, I spend a little of time to compact all this waste of space and make it like this:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
    }};
```

Now the question is: is there a way to instruct Eclipse to make more compact code, similar to this latest one? Is there some option, or is there some code that I can change?

Obviously this is just an example, I am not complaining about the Runnable() autocomplete code in itself, and it's not even a complain, but I would like Eclipse to behave differently in **any** similar case.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this following two steps:

**Step 1**

Create your Java formatting rules.

To edit your code formatting style go to *Preferences> Java> Code style> Formatting*. Then starting from a built in style create your own.

In particular you may be interested in *New Lines*, *Blank Lines* and *Control statement* tabs where you have the liberty of changing many settings.

**Step 2.**

Go to Preferences> Java> Editor> Save Actions and enable *Perform the selected actions on save* and check *Format source code*.

**Formatting immediately:**

In the case you don't want to wait a save command to apply format:

- Any Java template can be inserted in editor with formatting rules applied. Just make sure that *Use code formatter* is checked for every template. This is best solution for your question
- You can apply formatting with CTRL+SHIFT+F
- You can force a *Save all* when building, so practically, every time you build, you format.

Comment: This is a good solution, but just a workaround, it allows me to apply the formatting directly after writing it. It seems that anyway all this formatting is set in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor and Code Style, I will investigate a bit, thank you.

Comment: For Java templates, like 'if', if option *Use code formatter* is enabled, code formatting rule is directly applied without forcing it, that is when you are writing. Going to edit my answer.